# Some questions of using Redux in react

Tags: reactjs

```
//AddMemo.js
import React from 'react';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {memoControl, initialState} from './reducer';

function AddMemo(){
    const state=initialState;
    console.log(state);

    const dispatch=useDispatch();
    const onAddMemo=()=>dispatch({
        type:'ADD_MEMO',
        memos:{
            title:'',
            content:'',
            color:'white',
            num: num+1 //Question 1.
        }
    });

    return(
        <ul id="memoList" class="memo-list">
            <li id="addMemo" class="memo add" data-memo-num="-1" onClick={onAddMemo}> //Question 2.
              <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add new memo
            </li>
        </ul>
    );
}
export default AddMemo;


//reducer.js
const ADD_MEMO='ADD_MEMO';
const TOGGLE_MEMO='TOGGLE_MEMO';

//export const addMemo=()=>({type:ADD_MEMO});
export const toggleMemo=()=>({type:TOGGLE_MEMO});

export const initialState={
    current_memo:0,
    memos:[
        {
            title:'',
            content:'',
            color:'white',
            num:0
        },
        {
            title:'i am so tired',
            content:'',
            color:'white',
            num:0
        }
    ]   
};

export default function memoControl(state=initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_MEMO:
            return{
                ...state,
                memos:state.memos.concat(action.memos)
            }
        case TOGGLE_MEMO:
            return {
                ...state,
                current_memo:action.num
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

While using redux, I have a few questions.

1. I want to keep adding 1 to 'num' in the intialState value
   But I don't know how to access the num value in the intialState
2. If it's normal, when the id 'addMemo' is pressed, 'onAddMemo' should be dispatched as it runs. So there should be a 2nd array in intialState. But it doesn't work as expected. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not use the initial state in the component. Redux does not update the initial state it creates a new copy with the updated value.
2. Check the below example, it'll solve the issue.

**Note:** I'm assuming you have configured redux correctly.

```
//AddMemo.js
import React from 'react';
import {useDispatch, connect} from 'react-redux';
import {memoControl, initialState} from './reducer';

function AddMemo(props){
    console.log(props);

    const onAddMemo=()=> props.onAddMemo({
        title:'',
        content:'',
        color:'white',
        num: 1 //Question 1.
    })

    return(
        <ul id="memoList" class="memo-list">
            <li id="addMemo" class="memo add" data-memo-num="-1" onClick={onAddMemo}> //Question 2.
              <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add new memo
            </li>
        </ul>
    );
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    const onAddMemo = memos => dispatch({ type:'ADD_MEMO', memos });

    return {
        onAddMemo
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AddMemo);
```

Comment: It is said that props in onAddMemo function are not defined.

Comment: Even after copying and pasting the same, it says that num is not defined. And is it possible to dispatch without using useDispatch()?

Comment: num is not defined you should put default value, else check inside props what you are getting